# JavaScript/Node match returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, match

I want to get out of string containing HTML code, just one value. Therefore what I was trying was the following:

```
var test = '<div class="market_listing_largeimage"><img src="SOMEURLHERE" alt="" /></div>';
var test2 = test.match('<div class="market_listing_largeimage"><img src="' + '(.*)' + '" alt="" /><</div>');
```

My problem is that it returns null. I was googling for last hour, was trying different examples, it worked with string provided in example, but somehow, it doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with a regex is generally fraught with difficulties unless you know exactly what the source is going to look like.  It's much safer to turn into actual HTML objects and then walk the DOM to get the object and properties you want.

Comment: To get image src value, use `test.match('<img.*?src="(.*?)"')[1]`

Comment: You're right about difficulties, however I'm downloading the page, and from it's source I'm getting image SRC. Therefore I don't know any other way to get the image. Luckly for me, site I'm trying to get details from, isn't getting updates too frequent, so this workaway works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have additional `<` in your code.

This should work:

```
var test = '<div class="market_listing_largeimage"><img src="SOMEURLHERE" alt="" /></div>';
var test2 = test.match('<div class="market_listing_largeimage"><img src="' + '(.*)' + '" alt="" /></div>');
```